# I have this problem Checkpoint failed

Tags: monerod

[image]

questo è il mio problema cosa posso fare?

Comment: Did you try following the instruction (start like `monerod --enforce-dns-checkpointing`) ?

Comment: yes, I tried but the mistake is the same